# Magento 2.2.3 move block XML

Tags: magento2

I'm relatively new to Magento. Just trying to move a block, and as far as I understand I can archieve that via layout XMLS.

I want the checkout.registration block to come BEVORE the checkout.success block on the checkout success page.

So I copied the "checkout_onepage_success.xml" in my theme under view/frontend/layout and changed it. But I can't see the changes on the frontend (overriding the success.phtml worked, dev mode, cleared cache, even upgraded).

Also, I think it would be better to move the block instead of overriding the whole file. How can I update the file without overriding it? Do I use the same location or somewhere else? Does the location decide wheather to override or is there a signal I give in the file? I found many re

Cheers
Valentin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**checkout_onepage_success.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="checkout.registration" destination="content" before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thank you! Why will this not just replace / override the checkout_onepage_success.xml from the magento_checkout module? Just trying to understand